# Dúvida no uso da biblioteca lavacharts no Laravel consultado Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, gráfico

Senhores, estou usando a biblioteca do Google a Lavacharts, mas estou tenho o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu controller estou fazendo assim:

```
$graf = new Lavacharts;
$valor = $graf->DataTable();
$valores = Produtos::select("nome as 0", "preco as 1")->get()->toArray();
$valor->addStringColumn("Preço")
        ->addNumberColumn("Nome")
        ->addRows($valores);
$graf->BarChart('Preço', $valor);

return view('home', ["graf" => $graf ]);
```

em minha view peço para exibir de acordo com que o Biblioteca recomenta

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="pop_div"></div>
<?= $graf->render("BarChart", "Preço", "pop_div"); ?>
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Obrigado

Comment: O que aparece no código (view-source)?

Comment: Não aparece nada de errado, como se estivesse rodando tudo perfeitamente como você pode ver https://prnt.sc/mif76m @EduardoStuart

Comment: O que aparece para você se você `dd($valores)` (logo após a linha de $valores=...) ?  Tem certeza que existem valores a serem exibidos?

Comment: sim, tenho valores https://prnt.sc/mifb7e @EduardoStuart

Comment: Não seria as colunas trocadas? Apenas troque a ordem do select, preco primeiro e depios o nome.

Comment: Não retornou nada, https://prnt.sc/mifgpx @EduardoStuart

Comment: meu controller esta assim https://prnt.sc/mifk2j @EduardoStuart

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89439/discussion-between-cristiano-facirolli-and-eduardo-stuart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde @ Crsitiano, não sei se já conseguiu resolver seu problema, aqui eu fiz dessa forma:

```
    $graf = new Lavacharts;
    $valor = \Lava::DataTable();
    $valores = Produtos::select("nome as 0", "preco as 1")->get()->toArray();
    $valor->addStringColumn("Preço")
            ->addNumberColumn("Nome")
            ->addRows(["NomeDaLinha", $valores]);

    \Lava::BarChart(
        'Preço', $valor, [
        'title' => 'Seu título aqui: '. $valores,
        'height' => 400
        ]
    );

    return view('home');
```

Na view ficou assim:

```
<div id="poll_div"></div>

<?= Lava::render('BarChart', 'valor', 'poll_div') ?>
```

E deu certo, claro que eu adaptei um código meu para o seu...
Tenta quem sabe não funciona...

Abs...

Comment: Bom dia @GabrielSassaki já resolvemos este post. Muito obrigado pela ajuda